# How save data wp_editor() in custom plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am a beginner in create plugin.
I am creating custom plugin.
This is my code

```
defined('ABSPATH') or die('No script kiddies please!');

function reservationPlugin()
{
    add_menu_page('Reservation', 'Reservation', 4, 'reservation-Option', 'exampleMenu', 'dashicons-calendar', 3);
}

function exampleMenu()
{
    $content = '';
    $editor_id = 'mycustomeditor';
    wp_editor($content, $editor_id);
}
```

How can I save the content?
And after this show in front?
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it's as <**textarea**> and put in form

```
$content = '';
if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] != '') {
        $content=$_POST['mycustomeditor'];
    }
}

$editor_id = 'mycustomeditor';
?>
<form name="editorForm" method="post" action="">
    <?
    wp_editor($content, $editor_id);
    submit_button('save');
    ?>
</form>
```